# Is there an event that is called before the completion of the process on android?

Tags: java, android

Not only Activity, for the entire process. It is necessary that the process is not finished until the code inside onExit()  will be finished. No matter how much time will be spent on it.

onPause() of Activity is not suitable. If the user or OS want to kill process, code inside onPause() not will be finished if it take for example 2 hours.

Example:
User or OS want to kill process. This results in a call 
onExit(){
   my time - 2 hours
}
Only after onExit(), process will be killed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an event that is called before the completion of the process on android?

Not in the Android SDK.

> It is necessary that the process is not finished until the code inside onExit() will be finished

That too is not in the Android SDK.

Comment: If the user or OS want to exit process, process will be finished immediately or i have some time for save data? How long? If save function or other take 10 min?

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar: "process will be finished immediately" -- yes.

Comment: The only way to execute my code before process finished - it is onPause()? But i have little time if user immediately close application (exit process)?

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar: "The only way to execute my code before process finished - it is onPause()?" -- or any time before that. Waiting until the last possible moment to do some work is not always the best approach. "But i have little time if user immediately close application (exit process)?" -- at any point when your app is no longer in the foreground, your process can be terminated. If you have a bit of work that needs to be done and will take longer than a second or so, wrap that in an `IntentService`.